# I have to extract a word in Perl, using a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

The word starts with `-D` (it may also be `-d`).
Followed by zero or more spaces.
After that it's followed by a `$`.
Then the series is `{rajna_NAME}`.
To be brief

```
-d ${ranjana_wdgf_NAME}or -D${Tom_task_NAME}
```

I want to extract

```
ranjana_wdgf
Tom_task
```

My doubt is

```
if ( $word =~ m/^-D(\$)\|(\w*NAME)\b/)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes regexes are not as robust as other means.

For this case, I wouldn't mind giving [`Text::Balanced`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Balanced/) a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a **Regular Expression** to solve the problem,
then try this one

```
$word =~ m/\{(.*?)\_NAME/; # assuming that name is surrounded by curly brackets
```

**Updated:**

```
$word =~ m/-[dD]\s*\$\{(.*?)_NAME/; #assuming -d or -D always be there.
```

Comment: Is there any chance to include -D or -d in the regex as a filtering criterial allong with it should start with..Because its filtering sum other unwanted data..since the text file is large i am not able to provide the entire content

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question properly.
But looks like the code below solves your problem:

```
$ cat extract.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub extract_name($)
{
  my $s = shift;
  if($s =~ /^-[dD]\s*\${(.*)_NAME}$/)
    {
      print "$1\n";
    } 
  return;
}

extract_name('-d ${ranjana_wdgf_NAME}');
extract_name('-D${Tom_task_NAME}');
$ perl extract.pl 
ranjana_wdgf
Tom_task
$
```

Comment: @dmitryAwesome..Have few more doubts to be clarified with you

Comment: Are you talking about "shift" in this example?
It is used to access parameters passed to subroutine.
Alternatively, you can access parameters directly via $_[0], $_[1], etc.